# Jmeter 3.0 Нет HTTP Proxy Server

Tags: jmeter

Нет HTTP Proxy Server в версии 3.0, можно ли его поставить отдельно и как? В плагинах не нашел

Answer (score 2):

он называется Test Script Recorder. Находится там же, выглядит практически так же.